# Trigger Clarification

Tags: trigger, bulkification

Trigger Code:

> I have created custom field called Expected items in the order object

```
trigger updateorderstatus on OrderItem (after insert,after update) 
    {
        list<order> updateorder = new list<order>();
        set<id>updateorderid = new set<id>();
        if(trigger.isinsert)
        {
            for(OrderItem ot : trigger.new)
            {
                updateorderid.add(ot.OrderId);
            }
        }
        if(trigger.isupdate)
        {
            for(OrderItem ot : trigger.new)
            {
                updateorderid.add(ot.OrderId);
            }
        }
        updateorder = [select id,Status,Expected_Items__c,(select id from orderitems) from order where id in:updateorderid and Expected_Items__c >0 and Status ='Draft'];
        for(order orderlst : updateorder)
        {
            set<id> orderitemids = new set<id>();
            for(orderitem otlst : orderlst.orderitems)
            {
                orderitemids.add(otlst.id);
            }
            if(orderlst.Expected_Items__c >0 && orderlst.Expected_Items__c !=null)
            {
                if(orderlst.Expected_Items__c == orderitemids.size())
                {
                    orderlst.status ='Submitted';
                }
            }
        }
        if(updateorder.size()> 0)
        {  
            update updateorder;
        }
    }
```

First Case:

> If the order is inserted with the expected items field value as 2 and 
>   add two order products are added then the order status is changed to
>   submitted

Second Case:

> if the order is inserted with the empty field of expected items and
>   add two order products is saved as draft and while editing the order with the expected
>   items field value is changed to two, **it is showing error sfdc entity
>   Locked error,This error due to it will check for the first case itself
>   ,expected item value and order item size is equal,it will not going
>   for the Second order Product and update the order status in
>   secondorder product also**, How to Overcome this issue according to my
>   Trigger can anyone guide me for the Answer

**Please anyone guide me for the answer for above trigger should be work in both the scenarios**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a number of issues, which I'll outline, and hopefully we can get to the bottom of your problem.

```
trigger updateorderstatus on OrderItem (after insert,after update) 
{
    list<order> updateorder = new list<order>();
    set<id>updateorderid = new set<id>();
```

This following mess is completely unnecessary. We'll just iterate over the list in Trigger.new.

```
/*
    if(trigger.isinsert)
    {
        for(OrderItem ot : trigger.new)
        {
            updateorderid.add(ot.OrderId);
        }
    }
    if(trigger.isupdate)
    {
        for(OrderItem ot : trigger.new)
        {
            updateorderid.add(ot.OrderId);
        }
    }
*/

    for(OrderItem item: Trigger.new) {
        updateorderId.add(item.OrderId);
    }
```

Next, we can clean up and optimize this query in a few ways. First, we know that Status is Draft, so we don't need to query the field. Second, we don't need to query Id unless it's the only field we are querying. Third, we can use an AggreateResult query to keep things simple.

```
/*
    updateorder = [select id,Status,Expected_Items__c,(select id from orderitems) from order where id in:updateorderid and Expected_Items__c >0 and Status ='Draft'];
*/

    AggregateResult[] orderTally = 
        [SELECT COUNT(Id) sum, SUM(Order.Expected_Items__c) expect, OrderId Id
         FROM OrderItem 
         WHERE Order.Status = 'Draft' AND Order.Expected_Items__c > 0 AND OrderId = :updateorderId
         GROUP BY OrderId];
```

That makes all of the following code useless, because we can now use a trivial loop.

```
/*
    for(order orderlst : updateorder)
    {
        set<id> orderitemids = new set<id>();
        for(orderitem otlst : orderlst.orderitems)
        {
            orderitemids.add(otlst.id);
        }
        if(orderlst.Expected_Items__c >0 && orderlst.Expected_Items__c !=null)
        {
            if(orderlst.Expected_Items__c == orderitemids.size())
            {
                orderlst.status ='Submitted';
            }
        }
    }
*/

for(AggregateResult ar: orderTally) {
    if(ar.get('sum') == ar.get('expect')) {
        updateorder.add(new Order(Id=(Id)ar.get('Id'), Status='Submitted'));
    }
}
```

Finally, there's no point in checking if a list is empty before the DML; it's actually less efficient than just doing it.

```
/*
    if(updateorder.size()> 0)
    {  
*/
        update updateorder;
/*
    }
*/
}
```

As another minor note, you should always check for null before you check for a greater-than/less-than comparison when you need to. It wasn't necessary in this case, because we eliminated the code, and because you'd already filtered it out, so that's no longer relevant to this answer.

Here's the new, revised version of your trigger:

```
trigger updateorderstatus on OrderItem (after insert,after update) {
    list<order> updateorder = new list<order>();
    set<Id> updateorderId = new Set<Id>();

    for(OrderItem item: Trigger.new) {
        updateorderId.add(item.OrderId);
    }

    AggregateResult[] orderTally = 
        [SELECT COUNT(Id) sum, AVG(Order.Expected_Items__c) expect, OrderId Id
         FROM OrderItem 
         WHERE Order.Status = 'Draft' AND Order.Expected_Items__c > 0 AND OrderId = :updateorderId
         GROUP BY OrderId];

    for(AggregateResult ar: orderTally) {
        if((Decimal)ar.get('sum') == (Decimal)ar.get('expect')) {
            updateorder.add(new Order(Id=(Id)ar.get('Id'), Status='Submitted'));
        }
    }
    update updateorder;
}
```

Note: there may be another trigger, workflow rule, etc, causing the error, because I have actually tested this in my developer organization. You might need to read some debug logs to figure out why the recursion is happening.

Also, this may not work in some cases, for example, where someone deletes line items because they're over the expected value.

Comment: @user36188 Entity Locked usually means interaction from something else is causing the problem, possibly asynchronous code. You might actually need a locking statement to fix the problem, but it's hard to tell just from what you've posted. As for the AVG question, we need to do this because we need an aggregate function for the query to work, and AVG happens to return the correct value per order.

Comment: @user36188 Yes, I personally tested this code in my developer org before I posted it. Please feel free to try it for yourself.

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/152332/regarding-trigger-update @sfdcfox

Comment: can you guide me for the answer @sfdcfox

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple lines in your code that need changed. Even though your trigger is defined as AfterInsert and AfterUpdate, you may have some record locking going on.

You have `if(trigger.isinsert)` and `if(trigger.isupdate)` in your code. Prior to both of these, place an `if(trigger.isafter)` and see if that doesn't resolve your issue as in:

```
 if(trigger.isafter)
 {
    if(trigger.isinsert)
    {
        for(OrderItem ot : trigger.new)
        {
            updateorderid.add(ot.OrderId);
        }
    }
    if(trigger.isupdate)
    {
        for(OrderItem ot : trigger.new)
        {
            updateorderid.add(ot.OrderId);
        }
    }
  }
```

That's how the above part should be written.

You also have this line:

```
orderlst.Expected_Items__c == orderitemids.size()
```

This causes an issue for you that would prevent the insertion of the records initially if the orderiemids.size doesn't match (where you've entered 0 when there actually are 2 order items). This effectively becomes a validation rule. Instead of using it here, I recommend you create a separate validation rule for your page, assuming these records are always entered via a page. If they're not, then you'll want to allow partial success and add records to a list that don't meet this criteria.

The other thing to consider, especially in the AfterUpdate trigger, is your entry criteria. You don't appear to be looking to see if these values have changed between trigger.old and trigger.new. In your if statements, there's no comparison or criteria for entry. Perhaps what you want to do is exclude records for update where these two do not match.

Comment: You need to create the validation rule in Settings|Customize for OrderItem based on the two fields in question. Look in Salesforce Help for validation rules if you don't know how to write them. Give it a try and if you get stuck, post another question telling us where you're having difficulty.

Comment: While I generally like your answers, this one is just off-base. ☹

Comment: @sfdcfox I am strucked , can you guide me

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks for the feedback. Happens when you're in a hurry. Have edited and picked up some things of note that you've not covered in your answer.

Comment: @crmprogdev can you guide me http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/152332/regarding-trigger-update